# Redirecting not working, predefined pages with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have some pages, that are going to 404 page, and i have to redirect some of them to some other pages instead of 404. For ex. i have page, and i need to redirect it from  www.site.com/somelink/link to www.site.com/?q=somelink

I've tried this way : `Redirect 301 www.site.com/somelink/link http://www.site.com/?q=somelink` in htaccess, but this didnt give me result. Where am i mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` asuming you are using `apache` :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (/somelink/link) http://www.site.com/?q=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

By my own missunderstanding, i had to use `Redirect 301 /somelink/link http://www.site.com/?q=somelink`